# Does it make more sense to do `return '';` or `return null;` from within this switch statement?

Tags: javascript, null, switch-statement, break

For the following function, would it make more sense to `return ''` or `return null` from within the `default` clause?

```
const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );

  let computerChoice;
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      computerChoice = 'rock';
      break;
    case 1:
      computerChoice = 'paper';
      break;
    case 2:
      computerChoice = 'scissors';
      break;
    default:
      computerChoice = '';
  }

  return computerChoice; 
}
```

Or

```
const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 );

  let computerChoice;
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      computerChoice = 'rock';
      break;
    case 1:
      computerChoice = 'paper';
      break;
    case 2:
      computerChoice = 'scissors';
      break;
    default:
      computerChoice = null;
  }

  return computerChoice; 
}
```

Also, is it considered a good habit to include `break` even in the `default` clause?

Comment: It is redundant to break after a return. I feel this question is very opinion based, but returning null would be better than an empty string. An empty string just feels awkward and unusable. In this case, I would suggest throwing an error instead, since the default case should never be hit.

Comment: It should probably be `default: throw new Error('Unexpected forth choice')`?!

Comment: @Kobe Thank you for that. I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @Grateful I feel it would nicer to look at if you included break in the default case. This again is personal preference, since it doesn't matter whether it's there or not. But you could just avoid using a default case here by initialising `computerChoice` as null, and not including a default case. Then, if for some unknown reason you get a number other than 0, 1, or 2, null will be returned

Comment: @Kobe Once again, thank you. However, even in that case... Would it make more sense to initialise with `null` or `''`?

Comment: @Grateful `null`. I don't understand why you would want to return an empty string ever, unless it was user input. An empty string is a falsy value, but also a vaild return type. So if you had to check the type of output, you could not differenciate between `''` and `'rock'`, whereas with `null`, you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When will this ever need to return anything other than one of the three?

If the JS engine suddenly develops bugs in the Math, you might want to throw an error.

Otherwise just use the random number which will always be 0, 1 or 2 to [index an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) of the 3 choices. Note there is no need for an explicit return statement when there are no brackets

```js
const getComputerChoice = () => ["rock", "paper", "scissors"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log(getComputerChoice());
```

Comment: WOW! I am not used to this notation, so I have no idea what you just did there. Would you be kind enough to elaborate!?

Comment: @Grateful You know that `[..., ...]` makes an array? And you know that `a[...]` accesses an element of that array? It's that. Nothing more.

Comment: Can anybody explain how this solution was able to go from the switch statement to using square brackets? It almost looks like an array... But I have no idea how arrays were used to simulate a switch statement.

Comment: @Grateful You understand that `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` generates either 0, 1 or 2. This number is then used to access that index of the array `["rock", "paper", "scissors"]`. Then, the value is returned from the function, since we are using fat arrow syntax (`=>`), there's no need to use the return keyword.

Comment: @Grateful - I added https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements - the switching comes from the random element

Comment: @kobe Okay that finally makes sense to me now! Wow... How convenient!

Comment: @mplungjan Would you be ever so kind to explain what the differences are between using a switch statement and using an array like that. I never realised that they could be used interchangeably like that.

Comment: @Grateful Hmm, hard. I would never even consider a switch in this case. One would use a switch to avoid a nested if. But if the switch is just returning a string, then an array lookup makes more sense. In this case the value we switch on is an integer between 0 and something, that makes looking something up in an array, which is 0 based, even more useful. Let's say you had ten values and they were "duck", "owl", "dolphin", "shark", etc and you wanted to return bird, mammal or fish, then a switch with run-through and default makes much more sense